# Could I call action helper from custom helper?

Tags: ember.js, htmlbars

I use `ember.js` `v1.13.0` and have template helper

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(function(data, recordType, options) {
    data = data || '';
    if (recordType == 12) {
        //not escaped
        escaped = data + "<a href=\"#\">it's some extra button</a>";
    } else {
        var escaped = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(data);
        var matchURLs = /\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/gi;
        var replaceURL = function (str) {
            return "<a target=\"_blank\" href='" + (str.indexOf("://") === -1 ? "http://" : "") + str + "'>" + str + "</a>";
        }

        escaped = escaped.replace(matchURLs, replaceURL);
    }

    //nl2br
    escaped = escaped.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");


    return new Handlebars.SafeString(escaped);
});
```

My aim if helper gets record with specified type it will add button to end of record text. But when button is clicked it needs to call some action in my controller.

I have idea to call template's `action` helper from my helper when it will add the button.

Or maybe you can advice another aproach to add new button which call action in controller during rendering.

Comment: why don't you have button in template with if check using helper. like this `{{#if (helpername arguments) }} <button {{action 'actionName'}}</button>`